# Limitation to number of documents under one Collection in firebase firestore

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to firebase firestore and searched, but could not find the  limitation for the number of documents that can be handled under one collection. Can anybody help me out to know please.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

*firebaser here*

There is no documented limit to the number of documents that can be stored in a Cloud Firestore collection. The system is designed to scale to huge data sets.

Answer (score 13):

There is no limitation on the number of documents in Firestore collection but it has a limitation of the size of the document.
The maximum size of a document is roughly 1 MiB (1,048,576 bytes).

There are many more limits that are listed in the below link.
[Limits of firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#limits)

Answer (score 1):

There is no document limit under one collection

Official documentation for clearness: [Click here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields)

But there is limitation in maximum depth of subcollections

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't say.

However, you're allowed 1500 bytes for an id, which is approx 750 UTF-8 characters.

There are about 150,000 unicode characters.

That means there are approx 750^150000 possible ids, which is a number with about a million digits, so as good as infinite.

You'll run into other limits e.g. costs, before you get anywhere near that.