# Is there a limit to how many collections you can have in firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48634227/limitation-to-number-of-documents-under-one-collection-in-firebase-firestore) which explains there is no limit to the documents in a collection (which I understood was the case for scalability), however, is there a documented limit on collections?

My app will be multi-tenant with collections like `tenandId_collectionName` so I don't want to hit a limit as users grow.

Comment: did you find the number?

Comment: I didn't, I changed the way I did my implementation and have since abandoned that avenuue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Firebase Limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields) does not state any limits on collections, but there is a limit on the depth of sub-collections. The limit is that you can only go 100 subcollections deep, which is very large and you should never reach that point unless you have the most detailed and specific app in the world.

So to summarize, there are no limits on how many collections you have, just how deep you can go within a collection.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm not planning on nesting too much because it hinders indexing, searching etc so that's all good. Thanks.