# Firestore get all users data without loop all documents

Tags: firebase, loops, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore to build my app. But I'm having the issue that I need to get all users to recommend users other users. Currently, I solve this issue by writing all data that I need for the loop in an overview document inside my users collection. But I'm realizing that a single document can only be 1 MB. That means I can only store ~1000 users.

Example of my database

```
{
  'users': {
    'userId': 'username'
  }
}
```

How I can solve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48635757/7015400 You can have as many documents as you want under one collection.. so if each document is for one user, you can have more than 1000 users

Comment: Yes but I want the data from all users in a array but when I do this and I have for example 10000 users, I can only loop all users 5 times on each day with my free quota. This is my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 1MB limit per document is a hard limit.  It can't be exceeded.  If you have more items than can fit in a single document, you will need to move those items into individual documents.  Usually people use a nested subcollection for this.

If you are running into limits with your free allowance, obviously you will have to upgrade to a paid plan.  These limits simply cannot be exceeded and can't be designed around.

Comment: How can nested subcollections help me with my issue?

Comment: If you break up all the items into separate documents in a subcollection, you will not have a problem with the size of the original document.